# Why wont this function return any data?

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows, discord.js, readfile

I want to read a file using a function but it always just returns undefined.

```
function ReadFromFile(FileName) { 
    data = fs.readFile(`./ServerSaves/${FileName}.txt`, 'utf8', (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
            console.error(err);
            return;
        } 
            
        return data;
        
    }); 
    console.log(data)
    return data;
}
```

I tried many things already but the output was always either "undefined", "[object Promise]" or an error.

Comment: Because `readFile` is **asynchronous** (and doesn't return anything, see [the documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fsreadfilepath-options-callback)), but your function isn't. (Separately: Your code is falling prey to what I call [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html) -- declare your variables, like `data`.)